# Default text in chatter post

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I recently created a chatter group and I have been trying to get certain chatter posts sent to the chatter group via process builder. Salesforce doesn't allow rich text for feed items via automation so I want to default those chatter posts to mention the chatter group. Is there anyway that this is possible?

Comment: Have you tried at-mentioning the group within a chatter post action in the process builder?  That is probably the only way to do it.

Comment: The only way I've seen that is through the post to chatter action, and that brings me back to square one. Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Oh you want to add existing chatter posts to the group, I misunderstood.